# Как выводить объект с много вложенности в react?

Tags: reactjs

Не могу понять как выводить объекты которые имеют много вложенности и при этом чтобы не писать каждый раз отдельный блок, а они повторялись. Допустим там есть props.thema.test[0], props.thema.test[1],props.thema.test[2] и также к ответы должны быть (answer);
Вот мои пример. это тесты.
https://codepen.io/rusline/pen/JMmJQM?editors=0010
Если не отверывается вот код

```js
const thema = [{
  id: 1, 
  name: 'Тема первая',
  test: [
    [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Вопрос 1',
    id_theme: 1,
    answer: [ { id: 1, text: 'да', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
 { id: 2, text: 'нет', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
 { id: 3, text: 'не помню', id_question: 4, answer: 1 } ] },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Вопрос 2',
    id_theme: 1,
    answer: [ { id: 4, text: 'да', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
  { id: 5, text: 'нет', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
  { id: 6, text: 'не помню', id_question: 4, answer: 1 } ] },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Вопрос 3',
    id_theme: 1,
    answer: [{ id: 7, text: 'да', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
  { id: 8, text: 'нет', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
  { id: 9, text: 'не помню', id_question: 4, answer: 1 }] }]  
  ]
}]

class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div className='container'>
          <h1>{props.thema.name}</h1>
          <form>
            <div className='question'>
              <p>{props.thema.test.name}</p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <input type='radio' name={props.thema.test.answer.id_question.text}/>
                  <button>Ответить</button>
                </li>  
              </ul>  
            </div>  
          </form>  
        </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form thema={thema} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример полностью реализовано.

```
https://codepen.io/rusline/pen/JMmJQM?editors=0010
```

использована map

```js
const thema = [{
  id: 1, 
  name: 'Тема первая',
  test: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Вопрос 1',
      id_theme: 1,
      answer: [
        { id: 1, text: 'да', id_question: 1, answer: 0 },
        { id: 2, text: 'нет', id_question: 1, answer: 0 },
        { id: 3, text: 'не помню', id_question: 1, answer: 1 }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Вопрос 2',
      id_theme: 1,
      answer: [
        { id: 4, text: 'Вроде да', id_question: 2, answer: 0 },
        { id: 5, text: 'Вроде нет', id_question: 2, answer: 0 },
        { id: 6, text: 'не помню', id_question: 2, answer: 1 }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Вопрос 3',
      id_theme: 1,
      answer: [
        { id: 7, text: 'yes', id_question: 3, answer: 0 },
        { id: 8, text: 'no', id_question: 3, answer: 0 },
        { id: 9, text: 'not remember', id_question: 3, answer: 1 }
      ] 
    }
  ]  
}]

class Form extends React.Component{
  onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Нажата кнопка');
  }
  render(){
    const { thema } = this.props;
    
    return(
      <div>  
        {thema.map(({ id, name, test }) => (
          <div key={id} className='container'>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <form>
              {test.map(question => (
                <div key={question.id} className='question'>
                  <p>{question.name}</p>
                  <ul>
                      {question.answer.map(answer => (
                        <li key={answer.id}>
                          <input type='radio' name={answer.id_question}/>
                          {answer.text}
                        </li> 
                      ))} 
                  </ul>
                  <button onClick={this.onClick}>Ответить</button>
                </div>
              ))}  
            </form>  
          </div>
        ))}
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form thema={thema} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```